# Quoting numerical constants in Chez Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, chez-scheme

I am curious as to why Chez Scheme does not treat numbers as symbols. Whether they are in a list or are quoted alone, `number?` returns true, meaning that it was not made into a symbol. Is there a practical reason for this?

```lisp
Chez Scheme Version 9.5.4
Copyright 1984-2020 Cisco Systems, Inc.

> (number? (car '(1 2 3 4 5)))
#t
> (symbol? (car '(1 2 3 4 5)))
#f
> (define symbolic-num '5)
> (number? symbolic-num)
#t
> (symbol? symbolic-num)
#f
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to Chez, but is standard behaviour; see e.g. [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/):

> The rules for writing a symbol are exactly the same as the rules for writing an identifier [6.3.3 Symbols]

So a numeric literal can't be a symbol, because it's not an identifier.

Now, `'e` is shorthand for `(quote e)`, and

> `(quote <datum>)` evaluates to `<datum>`. [4.1.2  Literal expressions]

That is, `(quote 1)` - `'1` - evaluates to `1`, which is an integer, and `(quote a)` - `'a` - evaluates to `a`, which is a symbol.

> Numerical constants, string constants, character constants, and boolean constants evaluate ``to themselves''; they need not be quoted. [4.1.2  Literal expressions]

This gets a bit confusing because REPLs print some things in the "shorthand-quoted" form, but that's just an output convention.
Note that `(display 'a)` will show `a`, not `'a`.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.